# Digest Authentication with File upload

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How do I handle digest authentication when uploading a file with alamofire?  Here's what I'm currently doing.

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, URLString: postUrl,
                    multipartFormData: {
                        multipartFormData in
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: fileUrl, name: "filename")},
                    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tack on an `authenticate` call to the `upload` provided in the `encodingResult`.

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    URLString: "http://httpbin.org/post",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: rainbowImageURL, name: "rainbow")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.authenticate(user: "your_user", password: "your_password")
            upload.responseJSON { request, response, result in
                debugPrint(result)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```